# Using alphanumeric characters inside Curly braces in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, curly-braces

In **flex & bison** book by John Levine, i was reading the specification of the characters in regular expression. For curly braces i got this specification:

> If the braces contain one or two numbers, indicate the minimum and maximum
>   number of times the previous pattern can match. For example, A{1,3} matches one to three occurrences of the letter A, and 0{5} matches 00000. If the braces contain a name, they refer to a named pattern by that name.

But my confusion is with the line

> If the braces contain a name, they refer to a named pattern by that name.

What does it mean? I googled for examples like alphanumeric characters inside curly braces but couldn't get a satisfying one.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: @Jhecht thanks, but i couldn't understand their explanation :(

Comment: you name a group someone before hand so that you can reference it later. that's about as simple as I can boil that down.

Comment: thanks @Jhecht , i got that